# Radeon HD 4650 failed to load firmware

Tags: 14.04, radeon, gpu-driver

I have a VisionTek Radeon HD 4650 PCIex16 video card installed. I can't run anything other than the built-in display at 1024x768.

I get the following:

```
$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    5.527134] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    5.591796] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    5.591874] fb: conflicting fb hw usage radeondrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
[    5.592565] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV730 0x1002:0x9498 0x1545:0x4330).
[    5.592593] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFE9F0000
[    5.592596] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[    5.592752] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    5.592757] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[    5.592760] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[    5.592763] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[    5.593295] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[    5.593298] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    5.593313] [drm] Loading RV730 Microcode
[    5.593338] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.593342] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.608499] r600_cp: Failed to load firmware "radeon/RV730_pfp.bin"
[    5.608505] [drm:rv770_init] *ERROR* Failed to load firmware!
[    5.608511] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init
[    5.608517] [drm] radeon: finishing device.
[    5.630462] [drm] radeon: ttm finalized
[    5.630857] radeon: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -2
```

Answer (score -1):

Download file RV730_pfp.bin from this site http://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/ and put it in /lib/firmware/radeon

Comment: I do not see that file.